# What kind of technology is required to part water?

Tags: technology, weapons

Many biblical stories often depicts parting of water most famously by Moses at the red/reeds sea. I have considered using present day science to explain Moses's feat but that proved impossible, my question is what kind of technology in the future would be required in order to part water? (I also remember that kind of power was used to drown many Egyptian soldiers in one swept.)

Comment: I seem to remember a physical explanation for this event involving a volcano or earthquake at the other end of the Red Sea.

Comment: red sea parting is a Hollywood construct. the true parted sea is the sea of reeds near Nile delta which from the name you guess correctly that it boggy and prone to sinkholes which cause part of it to dry and then refill

Comment: @Frank Cedeno thanks for reminding me, I hope this question will not escalate into a religious debate as I would promptly omit the name entirely should it provoke any scholar.

Comment: If you're Moses, a stick should do the trick.

Comment: Do you mean an actual thing (like a weapon), or do you mean "how to do it?"  I think we expend a huge amount of cost with strong polymer plastics installed and braced with incredible logistics to make you a 2km long, 40m deep pathway from Jebel Atakh to Gad Al Markoub, going from Egypt to the Arabian peninsula of Egypt near Suez.  Doesn't sound like this is what you're after.

Comment: @Mikey I'm not after the underwater tunnel and the blow up to collapse the structure and bury my enemy within, I want to how how to do it using technology of the future.

Comment: One technology that can be used to part water is walls.

Comment: @Dave Halsall according to a reliable dictionary the definition of the part being a verb is for things to move away from each other so may I know what kind of wall are you recommending?

Comment: Levees, dams, dykes. If you displace water with solid material, are you not parting it?

Comment: @FrankCedeno Not a religious point. But likely the first comment by frostfyre is correct; the facts of the story seem to indicate geological disturbance, since, there was ground shaking and the inability to use chariots due to wheel failure, and a tsunami at the end.

Comment: If you want "technology of the future", how is that different, in our poor modern ignorance, from magic?

If you're really interested in how the seas might have been parted, who not first watch some of the several doccoes available on TV or download channels and report back what they failed to explain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The future ACME Water Parter

Water is a diamagnetic material. That means you can use magnetic fields to part water. [Frogs have been levitated using the water in their bodies](http://www.physics.org/facts/frog-really.asp), so we can already control water using magnetic waves to some extent.

In the future, larger, stronger magnetic fields could allow us to acheive exactly what you speak of.

Comment: It would affect the people trying to cross too. What a mess: try to use the nice dry path and your water-rich body gets tossed out of the exclusion zone, too!

Comment: @JDługosz He never said people had to walk through it :P He just asked to part the water.

Comment: This is an example for the need for a clear requirements document.  A passive-agressive engineer will deliver exactly what the customer asked for.  Could make for a funny vignette.

Answer (score 1):

## Wave superposition.

Like a rogue wave, only a trough. Set up various resonators and different places, ahead of time. Allow the waves to spread with constant input of energy to distribute the motion throughout the body of water.  At a pre-determined time and place, (nearly) all the water rushes away from the spot.

## Transparent Aluminum

Sheets of strong material extend out of the bottom of the body of water, either rising out from a stowed position, or self-assembling to rapidly grow in place.  This forms a robust barrier which forms a coffer dam.

Answer (score 0):

1. A couple of black holes should it. One on either side and their gravity pulls the water apart.
2. You don't specify the direction of the parting.  A [downburst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downburst) is a strong ground-level wind system that emanates from a single source above and blows radially, that is, in a straight line in all directions, from the point of contact at ground level. This would make a circular island that was lower than the water around it. Along an extended weather front, the downburst could be more linear, forming an inverted causeway.

Comment: Item 1 is a bit absurd I think, would black holes empty the water along with all the insoluble stuffs?

Answer (score 0):

the cheapest and most reliable way to do that is just outright lying.

Make sure someone tells you had that kind of power. Use some extra knowledge to make sure the group of people you want to lead through the gap is not where they were before. And make sure your enemies don't see the trick (and neither the quicksand, or deathtraps, or whatever) when they come rushing behind.

Then, with carefully spread rumour and not many survivors on the enemy side, you are set.

The survivors might even be encouraged to help spread the story (and be set free for this purpose exactly).